# Linux - printable characters

Tags: linux, file, directory, character

How can I count all the printable characters (excepting space and comma) that exist in all the files from a directory? I tried to use some pipes, but it does not return anything.

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This perl one liner

sets a counter to zero ($c)

Looks for printable characters see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#POSIX-Character-Classes and adds the count of them to $c

finally the count is shown

The * indicates all files in current directory

```
perl -n -e 'BEGIN {$c=0} $c+=()=/([:print:])/g; END {print $c}' *
```